# Center span below another span

Tags: html, css

I've got two paragraphs below each other both including 3 spans.
The upper spans have the text "Auftrag 1-3", the lower ones "Download".

I want the bottom spans (Download) to be directly centered below "Auftrag 1-3".

Right now only the middle one is perfectly centered, you can have a look at http://beta.playlikelars.de/iv.php if you didn't understood the text above.

```css
#content1 p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

#content1 .top {
  background: rgb(11, 81, 146);
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
}

#content1 .bottom {
  background: #d6d6d6;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="content1">

  <p>
    <span class="top">Auftrag 1</span>
    <span class="top">Auftrag 2</span>
    <span class="top">Auftrag 3</span>
  </p>

  <p>
    <span class="bottom">Download</span>
    <span class="bottom">Download</span>
    <span class="bottom">Download</span>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't have a code like `<span>Auftrag1<br> <download></span><span>Auftrag2<br> Download</span>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a table, not `<p>` and `<span>` tags. Tables are by far the shortest and clearest way of doing this.

```css
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Auftrag 1</td>
    <td>Auftrag 2</td>
    <td>Auftrag 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Download</td>
    <td>Download</td>
    <td>Download</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The css property `display: table` can also mimic this:

```css
span {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
}

p {
    display: table-row;
}

div {
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Auftrag 1</span>
    <span>Auftrag 2</span>
    <span>Auftrag 3</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Download</span>
    <span>Download</span>
    <span>Download</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like I'm not able to get a margin or padding between those rows?
I've added a span including "´" and colored it white to get an invisible one, but could I also add one between the "Auftrag 1" and "Auftrag 2"?

Comment: @Lars The elements in tables can be styled as any other box layout element.

Comment: @StephenLeppik No, table cell's can't be styled as _any other box layout_ element. I.e margin's doesn't work, so create a _gap_ between 2 cells takes some tricks that might not work cross browsers.

Comment: @LGSon we already had a flexbox answer. You could have upvoted that instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to separate the buttons into their own divs, and then make sure to give margin on both sides if you want the elements to stay centered. if you just want the text centered `text-align: center;` will center the content of an element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container-btns {
  margin: 15px;
}

.top {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bottom {
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-btns">
    <div class="top">Auftrag 1</div>
    <div class="bottom">Download</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-btns">
    <div class="top">Auftrag 3</div>
    <div class="bottom">Download</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-btns">
    <div class="top">Auftrag 2</div>
    <div class="bottom">Download</div>
  </div>
</div>
```